# hd graphics 3000 driver won't fully install on dell latitude E6520

Tags: laptop, drivers, graphics-card

I have a Dell latitude E6520  ..cannot get the intel hd graphics 3000 driver to fully install. unable to use duel monitors.  I'm a rockclimber not a tech guy.  I have tried updating and reinstalling with no luck

Comment: You don't specify what version of Windows you are using.  You need to provide more information other than "it won't fully install"

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more and assuming you reinstalled the Operating system, you have to install Dell drivers in a certain order for all of them to successfully install.

[Here is the order for your specific Model](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln284405/dell-latitude-e6520-windows-8-driver-installation-guide?lang=en)

Order is same regardless of Windows version.

[Here is your Drivers page](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/latitude-e6520/drivers)